# Horizontal Scrollbar replication

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with some hidden td's which has a horizontal scrollbar corresponds to the table's width. On load the table's width doesn't have scroll as we click a Expand button the hidden td's are opened and table has a width more the viewing space so scrollbar is populated as expected.

Now, i have a scrollbar equivalent to the table's as mentioend above; but the scrollbar is not getting updated when the Expand button is clicked on the go; it remains the same as the time on load.

Can we any technique to replicate the same behaviour of the table/div element scrollbar into a dummy scrollbar??

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Can you provide any code or fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I use to create a double scroll - Meaning attaching a scroll to the top of an element, since there is by default only one at the bottom:

```
function appendFakeScroll(elementToAttachScrollTo) {

    var newElementId = elementToAttachScrollTo[0].id + "Fake";

    // Check if we already have a fake scroll
    if (!$("#" + newElementId)[0]) {

        // No fake scroll exist, let's create a container for the scroll. It has to be the same width as the element we just expanded.
        var html = '<div style="overflow:auto;width:' + elementToAttachScrollTo.width() + 'px;height:17px;" id="' + newElementId + '">';
            html += '<div style="width:' + elementToAttachScrollTo[0].scrollWidth + 'px; height: 17px;"></div>';
            html += '</div>';

        // Here we attach the created scrollbar to the top of the element with .before()
        elementToAttachScrollTo.before(html);
    }

    // Create a jquery objekt of the now created fake scrollbar
    var fakeScroll = $("#" + newElementId);

    // Send the element we have the scrollbars in, as well as the fake scrollbar, 
    // to a function that links them together, so that scrolling the fake one
    // also scroll the window and the real scrollbar, and wise versa
    linkScrollWindows(elementToAttachScrollTo, fakeScroll);

}

function linkScrollWindows(elementToAttachScrollTo, fakeScroll) {

    fakeScroll.scroll(function () {
        elementToAttachScrollTo.scrollLeft(fakeScroll.scrollLeft());
    });

    elementToAttachScrollTo.scroll(function () {
        fakeScroll.scrollLeft(elementToAttachScrollTo.scrollLeft());
    });
}
```